# no matching function for call to 'regex_match'

Tags: c++, regex

Can anyone tell me why function regex_match is not working. It is always giving error saying `[cquery] no matching function for call to 'regex_match'`.
I am familiar with regex library of python but I was trying whether this works for cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
 
int main ()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;
regex r("^[a-m]+$");
regex r2("^[N-Z]+$");
bool b = false;
while(t--)
{
  
  int k;
  cin>>k;
  string str;
  cin>>str;
  for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
  {
    if ( regex_match(str[i],r))
      b = true;
    else if ( regex_match(str[i],r2))
      b = true;
    else
      b = false;
  }
  if (b == true)
    cout<<"YES";
  else
    cout<<"NO";  
}
}
```

**Error**

[image: error]

I tried for `regex_search` but then also same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you are tring to pass char as input to `regex_match` my guess is that you want to match substring so in order to achieve this you should change line to this:

```
regex_match(str.substr(i, str.size() - 1),r2)
```

below line pass first parameter as char **which is wrong**:

```
regex_match(str[i],r2)
```